# ng new says lot of packages are deprecated

Tags: npm, angular-cli

I'm new to Angular, and I installed it one week ago. Didn't pay attention on first use, but today I'm creating a new empty project with `ng new`, and on almost each package, it says it is deprecated, or "no longer maintained" and so on :

```
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.10: core-js@<3.0 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.9: One of your dependencies needs to upgrade to fsevents v2: 1) Proper nodejs v10+ support 2) No more fetching binaries from AWS, smaller package size
```

How is it possible and how can I update npm to avoid this and ensure to have last versions of packages?

Comment: What version of the angular cli do you have? you can find out by running `ng --version` in your terminal

Answer (score 1):

`core-js` is now at version 3.4.7. For updating, go to your project route and type into the terminal:

```
npm install --save core-js@3
```

This will update you to the latest version.